# What does someone do or what someone does?

Tags: grammar

Should it be *what does someone do* or *what someone does*?

For example, is it..

> Jerry will have to think about what does he want more.

vs

> Jerry will have to think about what he wants more.

Comment: "Jerry will have to think about what he wants more" is correct and the other one is not.

Comment: Talk is cheap, but "what someone does" reveals the truth. The choices in the title can both work, but they don't match the examples, which @JulesCocovin addresses.

Comment: This question belongs on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/)